# Hide scrollbar in FlatList (React Native) in Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use FlatList (React-native) in my app. I am using it horizontally and can see the scrollbar. There is an option in ScrollView to hide the scrollbar but not in FlatList. Has anyone been able to hide it some other way. I tried using the solution of parent & child container ([Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)) but did not work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

const data = [
    { id: 1, title: 'title 1', details: 'details 1 details 1 details 1' },
    { id: 2, title: 'title 2', details: 'details 2 details 2 details 2 details 2 details 2 details 2' },
    { id: 3, title: 'title 3', details: 'details 3 details 3' },
    { id: 4, title: 'title 4 title 4', details: 'details 4' },
];
class CategoryRow extends Component {

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    _renderItem = (item) => {
        return (
            <Card style={styles.cardContainer}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>   
                <Text>{item.details}</Text> 
            </Card>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, overflow:'hidden' }}>
                <View style={{ overflow:'hidden' }}>
                    <Text>Category 1</Text>
                    <FlatList
                        horizontal
                        data={data}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => this._renderItem(item)}
                        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}

                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardContainer: {
        width: 140,
        height: 150,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'grey',
        overflow: 'scroll',
    },
})

export default CategoryRow;
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

disable vertical and horizontal scroll indicator

```
<ScrollView
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
 />
```

Answer (score 292):

Just add

```
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
```

Comment: It worked but it is not mentioned in the official document as the prop for FlatList.

Comment: @sushilbansal because this prop inherits from ScrollView, not necesary to re-documentate....

Comment: Thx, works with both `FlatList` and `ScrollView`

Answer (score 33):

If you are trying to hide the vertical scrollbar use this:

```
showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
```

Answer (score 26):

`FlatList` is inherited from `VirtualizedList`.
`VirtualizedList` is inherited from `ScrollView`.
So you can use `ScrollView` props to hide scrollBar indicators in `FlatList`.

```html
<FlatList
  ...
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

try this to make ListView horizontal add (horizontal={true}) mentioned below and if you just want to hide the scrollbar just add (showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false})

```
<ListView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal={true} />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        <FlatList
            .....
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
```

**Just add this code**

Answer (score 1):

On my case using `Animated` version of the `Flatlist` fixed the problem:

```js
<Animated.FlatList
  ...
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

FlatList is inherited from VirtualizedList.
VirtualizedList is inherited from ScrollView.
So you can use ScrollView props to hide scrollBar indicators in FlatList.

```html
<FlatList
  ...
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  ...
/>
```